FullScreen mode goes to black after rotating the android mobile device
Device: HUAWEI Y6P Android: 10 Chrome version: 99.0.4844.73
Steps to reproduce the problem:

Open Google Chrome for Android (in landscape mode)
Rotate the device 180 degrees
Enter FullScreen mode via the requestFullscreen API
The screen will go completely black

Tested with other Chrome versions: 97 ~ 98 (no black screen issue) ~ 99 ~ 108 (black screen issue) -> 109 ~ 126 (no black screen issue)
I found this issue in the Chrome issue tracker.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/40826301
Since it is unclear whether this issue has been fixed, I would like to inquire about the status of this bug. If it has been fixed, could you please specify the exact version after which the fix was applied?
